# Code that distinguishes between dev and prod

Tags: java, spring

Normally I use `spring.profiles.active` to handle the differences between development and production, but how do I resolve the differences when they occur in my code?

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
        chromeOptions.setBinary("path"); // only used in dev
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
```

I don't need to specify binary paths in production environment, I would like to know the best practices for solving such problems!

Comment: Condition the execution of the code with something specific to the environment, such as an environment variable.

Comment: Is this not a Spring project?

Comment: This question is unanswerable.  We have no idea what context this block of code is called in, what framework (if any) is in use, or any other details about this.  There are myriad ways to go about solving a problem like this but without knowing more about how you've actually instrumented this environment, we're going to be making far too many suggestions as opposed to any that could be distilled into a coherent answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring a Spring bean, create a `@Configuration` and provide the specifically-configured beans via `@Bean` methods. You can select which bean method will be used via `@Profile`.

```
@Configuration
public class ChromeConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public ChromeOptions getProdChromeOptions() {
        // Do your production configuration here.
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public ChromeOptions getDevChromeOptions() {
        // Do your dev specific configuration here.
    }
}
```

Have an internal method that does any of the shared configuration then the environment specific stuff can happen in each of the profiled methods.